What are the Kubernetes RBAC verbs and resources which allow "kubectl rollout restart" a deployment?
What are the Kubernetes RBAC verbs and resources which allow kubectl rollout restart a deployment?
At this moment the current RBAC verbs are create, delete, deletecollection, get, list, patch, update, watch.  May you please provide the reasons also?
Since it is about a rollout restart of a deployment, does the resources in the role's/clusterrole's rules should include pods and replicasets ? I mean the pods are deleted and created again and the replicaset is also deleted and created again.
And in general, how to tell which minimal Kubernetes RBAC resources and verbs are needed in the role/clusterrole in order to allow certain kubectl commands ?
Thank you.

kubectl rollout restart changes a field in the Deployment spec which causes the existing Pods to be out-of-date; see for example How to rolling restart pods without changing deployment yaml in kubernetes?.  It doesn't directly modify the underlying ReplicaSets or Pods.  How is this permission question related to the code you're writing?

@DavidMaze , since "Kubernetes will start the rolling update process, which involves creating new pods with the updated configuration and gradually replacing the old pods." doesn't this mean that some permissions are needed to delete and recreate the pods?

Yes, but Kubernetes itself includes controllers that create ReplicaSets and Pods, and those controllers need the corresponding permissions, not your application code.

Pausing and unpausing rollouts is basically just setting or unsetting of the Deployment.spec.paused field. Thus in order to be able to know if anything needs to be done the verb get is necessary, and in order to make any changes the verb patch is necessary. The resource to which the verb needs to apply is Deployment, thus you can use following RBAC to allow kubectl rollout pause and kubectl rollout restart:
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    verbs: ["get", "patch"]

